# Steps to install software on Windows

Tags: windows, installation

What are the steps to install my software on Windows 7/8/10?

This is what I know:

Default path to copy files is Program Files (x86) for my 32 bit app on 64 bit system (or Program Files on 32 bit). One need Administrator provilege to copy my software's data there. I then have to create registry record in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall (or without WOW6432Node for 32 bit system) to be able to uninstall software (it appers in uninstall software list). Then I can create shortcuts on user's desktop and start menu.

Is there anything else I should pay attention to when installing software on Windows?

Comment: Installer creation tools take care of this for you, you should use one.

Comment: I used them till now (Inno Setup) but I need to customize the installer, hence I would like to create one.